# How can I write only three e-mail adress in one row

Tags: microsoft-word

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1eN7.png]

-First four rows represents the format that I'm looking for (but I don't really want to hit the enter button continously.
All e-mail adresses are seperated by semicolons (but mail providers might be different).

I think it can be a programming question. Looking for your answers.

Comment: SuperUser isn't a script-writing service. What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't really need programming to solve your problem.

Use find and replace, in the dialog form:

- mark "use wildcards"
- find what: `([!;]@;[!;]@;[!;]@;)`
- replace to: `\1^l`
- click "replace all"

This can add multiple line breaks, so if you append entries to your document after some content is already formatted, then selected the new entries before doing replacement.